# C# regular expression - get row data from Excel formula with R1C1 references

Tags: c#, regex, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get references of rows in Excel using regex. For instance, I have a formula:

```
=SUM(R[-3]C[-1];R[-3]C;R[-3]C[2];R[-1]C[2]:R[1]C[3];RC[-1])
```

and I need to get numbers only `-3`, `-3`, `-3`, `-1`, `1`, `0`

Currently, I am using regex pattern:

```
=?(R\[[-0-9]*\]|RC)
```

It gives me:

[image: result]

But it's necessary to get numbers only. Moreover, instead of `RC` I have to obtain `0`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using VBA macro? This does not seem possible without VBA

Comment: @Slai, I'm using C#

Comment: I'd capture all results pertinent with `(RC?\[-?[0-9]*\])` then in `C#` extract numbers needed from `R[x]`, then get `0` from `RC[y]`.

Comment: your regex can be used by moving the parentheses a bit and getting the last group of each match https://regex101.com/r/9BFhAF but note that `R[-1]C[2]:R[1]C[3]` references 3 rows : -1, 0, and 1. Do you get the formula with Interop.Excel?

Comment: @Slai, yes, I am using Interop.Excel. Using groups I could obtain numbers. Thanks. By the way, you have shown a cool website for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close - if you add another capturing group in your regex then you can pull out the `x` from `R[x]`. So your regex will be:

`=?(R\[([-0-9]*)\]|RC)`

Note it's your regex with extra brackets around `[-0-9]*`.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string formula = "=SUM(R[-3]C[-1];R[-3]C;R[-3]C[2];R[-1]C[2]:R[1]C[3];RC[-1])";
            string pattern = @"=?(R\[([-0-9]*)\]|RC)";
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex parser = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches;

            // parse formula
            matches = parser.Matches(formula);

            // iterate results
            foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches)
            {
                if (match.Groups[0].Value == "RC")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("0");
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it, but you can get all of the rows referenced in a formula with something like this:

```
Range formulaCell = worksheet.Range("A1");
Range referencedRange = formulaCell.DirectPrecedents;

foreach(Range area in referencedRange.Areas)
    foreach(Range cell in area.Cells)
        Debug.Print((cell.Row - formulaCell.Row).ToString);    // -3, -3, -3, -1, 0, 1, 0
```